# Iphone: Check List

Tags: iphone

Is there standard way to implement standard Iphone Check List like when you choose ringtone in Settings ? When you click on a row and checkmark appears ...

Or I should draw a checkmark by myself and set it by row index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to actually draw it. You can use:

[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

Comment: Yep..Found that...But I thought that there should be a standard table view mode..And I don't need to do anything...

Comment: A little elbow grease didn't hurt anyone :)

Comment: Yep...But what if I want to do a lot of settings in my app ? List settings... And for every setting I should write a lot of code...? In android that works better..

Comment: You could build a checkmark tableViewController and reuse that.. Sorry, but that's the way it goes :)